# How to indent after a defined sign on Sublimtext3

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, indentation

Is there a way on sublime text to indent in that way :

```
var1 = 1
myvar2 = 2
thisisvar3 = 3
```

would become

```
var1       = 1
myvar2     = 2
thisisvar3 = 3
```

Thank you so much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Alignment](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Alignment) plugin for this.

First, install the plugin using the command palette: search for *Package Control > Install package*, then for *"Alignment"*.

Then configure the plugin by navigating to *Preferences > Package Settings > Alignment > Settings - User*. Add this content to the appearing empty configuration file:

```
{
    "alignment_chars": [
        "="
    ]
}
```

Then in your code, select the lines you want to format this way, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.